# What religious items should a Muslim include on their CV?

Tags: work

In my line of work, I sometimes read people's [CV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae)s, e.g. for applications to be a student in our research group, or if someone wants to work for our lab.  Sometimes Muslim applicants list their religion along with other details, e.g., father's name.  I'm not sure if this is an Islamic matter, or just a cultural preference.

**Question**: What religious items should a Muslim include on their CV?

I could imagine that, when applying for jobs, etc., a Muslim woman could include her guardian's name (provided she has a guardian), or even his contact details, so that the company can verify that she has her guardian's permission to work.

In [Is it appropriate to mention one's religion in an academic CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58832/is-it-appropriate-to-mention-ones-religion-in-an-academic-cv), the author mentioned two other cases of Muslims mentioning their religion, and the answers suggested it could be problematic.

Comment: AFAIK every country has some specifications when it comes to job applications for example in Germany only the highest education level must appear on CV and religion isn't a part of the CV at all except for voluntary service if you mentioned it. I'm not familiar with CV's in other Muslim countries, but it appears to me rather strange to include the religion!

Comment: In strictly secular countries, mentioning your religion is either forbidden or seen badly, in order to avoid both positive and negative discrimination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing. Unless you want to do some research for religious studies where having a hands on experience with that sect, religion is a bonus.

I suspect some have mentioned their father's name as they don't have a last name, their full name is 'John son of Jack'. Or the person was a super-religious but not aware of social norms

Comment: Of course if it is a qualification for the applied job one should quote it! +1